# Polar chart with highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I need to create a chart like this one
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/110303712770402448748/albums/5891900514264118753/5891900515184170482?sqi=100875929141897651837&sqsi=9f68aae7-20ae-4a7e-b08c-3df05cfb5f57&pid=5891900515184170482&oid=110303712770402448748

This is what i have riht now with highcharts
http://jsfiddle.net/bcMYf/

I need to know how to group the series of each line and how to represent a info using not just columns, but also lines.

I try using the above code to group de columns, that way one is above another, so what i need now is to represent the columns using lines, like in the image example.

```
column: {           
  grouping: false
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use objects as points instead of data module, see: http://jsfiddle.net/r9CJw/

```
    series: [{
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 10
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 15
        }, {
            x: 5,
            y: 12
        }]

    }, {
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 8
        }, {
            x: 2,
            y: 9
        }, {
            x: 5,
            y: 10
        }]

    }, {
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            low: 3,
            y: 3.5
        }, {
            x: 2,
            low: 5,
            y: 5.5
        }, {
            x: 5,
            low: 6,
            y: 6.5
        }]

    }]
```

`low` option is to set where bar should start - now green bars looks like a line. There is only one problem - you need to calculate what value for a low should be to display proper y-value, and still have bar with proper height.